# Preserve formatting in gridView when printing?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have a gridView table that works great on my page. However, I need to have an option to print this. With the code I have so far, the formatting I have set up for my main page's gridview is removed when it is opened in the new window for printing. (And, oddly enough, when it actually prints - even more formatting is removed).

I'll try to include all the relevant code I have so far:

JavaScript

```
function CallPrint(strid) {
  var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
  var strOldOne = prtContent.innerHTML;
  var WinPrint = window.open(
    "",
    "",
    "scrollbars=yes,width=950,height=700,left=0,top=0"
  );
  WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
  WinPrint.document.close();
  WinPrint.focus();
  WinPrint.print();
  WinPrint.close();
  prtContent.innerHTML = strOldOne;
}
```

GridView's html/asp

```
<div id="panelGv" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="prodGv" BorderWidth="1px" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RECORD_NUM" DataSourceID="prodDataSource" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered " Width="100%" Height="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" CaptionAlign="Top"
    CellPadding="2" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="15pt">
    <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Italic="False" Font-Size="19pt" Wrap="True" BorderColor="#999999" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle BorderColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" BorderColor="#999999" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="15pt" Height="45px" Wrap="True" Font-Italic="False" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="#999999" />
    <PagerSettings Visible="False" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="#000066" BorderColor="#999999" />
    <%-- columns etc --%>
  </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And the print button

```
<asp:button ID="btnPrint" OnClientClick="javascript:CallPrint('panelGv');"
Runat="Server" CssClass="btn btn-default" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" Font-Size="14pt" Height="40px" Text="Print" Width="120px" />
```

My question is, how can I get the table to print exactly how it appears on the main page? When a new window is opened, the color is removed, but it still looks decent. However, the print preview shows a table which is completely unformatted - and stretched to fit the entire page such that it looks ridiculous.

Thank you so much. If I can clarify further please let me know, thank you.